# How do I create a script to delete all objects sharing the same texture/material in all collections?

Tags: python, materials, scripting

The project I'm working on in Blender has objects that aren't desired from the mesh rips I've pulled from PPSSPP using a tool called NinjaRipper. I'm looking to put together a script that targets meshes with a specific texture(and any iterations like "Texture.png.01") and have the objects deleted from all collections it is linked to. I have been looking at the python api documentation and found `bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=True)` which seems to be the end goal of the script but I'm unsure how to go about targeting objects sharing the same material/texture and their iterations, selecting them, and deleting them.

Comment: iterate over `bpy.data.materials` searching the node trees for image textures.  Each time you find an image texture check the image. If it's one you want to delete, add the material to a list.  Then iterate over `bpy.data.objects` searching the material slots of each object.  If any of the material slots have any of the materials you found in the first search, delete the object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a list of the relevant textures, something like this:

```py
texture_names = [
    "texture1.jpg",
    "texture2.jpg",
    "Metal007_1K_Color.jpg"
]
```

replacing my three sample strings with whatever textures you want.  Once you've don that, this code will

- First find all of the materials that use *any* of the textures in your list and
- Then remove any object that uses *any* of the named materials.

```py
import bpy

texture_names = [
    "texture1.jpg",
    "texture2.jpg",
    "Metal007_1K_Color.jpg"
]

wanted = []

for material in bpy.data.materials:
    node_tree = material.node_tree
    if node_tree:
        for node in node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == "TEX_IMAGE" and node.image.name in texture_names:
                wanted.append(material)

for object in bpy.data.objects:
    for slot in object.material_slots:
        if slot.material in wanted:
            print(object.name, slot.material.name)
            bpy.data.objects.remove(object)
```

To do this from the known materials,  use a slightly different setup

````py
import bpy
material_names = [
    #Fill this with strings of material names
]

for object in bpy.data.objects:
    for slot in object.material_slots:
        if slot.material.name in material_names:
            print(object.name, slot.material.name)
            bpy.data.objects.remove(object)
```
````